# Why are Application Insight and AppService metrics different?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I plugged my web site (Azure App Service) to Application Insight following this post : https://azure.microsoft.com/fr-fr/documentation/articles/app-insights-start-monitoring-app-health-usage/

I got some data on my graphs, but If I go on my web app I have different data :

- at 9pm the App Service reports "6.84s average response time"
- at 9pm the Application Insight reports "3.1s serverresponse time"

It's the same for the requests count (20.55k vs 21.65k).

There is no filters on my Application Insight graph.

What should I trust ?

Comment: An AppService can hold several Web Apps. The Application Insight targets the Web App particulary. Do you by any chance, have more than one Web App in that AppService?

Comment: "An AppService can hold several Web Apps.". Not sure about that. An App Plan can hold multiple web site but a web site is a appservice. I have only one Web App anyway.

Comment: It can, depending on your price tier, is the number of Apps in the same App Service that share the same resources [source](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/#app-service-limits)

Comment: There is no pricing tier on app services (there is on plan though), and I only have on web app on the service, on the plan, no deployment slot or virtual directory (if that's what you mean) : 1 web site, 1 service, 1 plan, 1 app insight

Comment: Then it beats me completely. For performance analysis I always used AppInsights (never looked at the App Service for those metrics) or NewRelic.

Comment: Just try to compare them, I guess it's because Applicaiton Insight is at the application level and  the app service is at the VM level (for instance the favico loading won't appear in App Insight but it will on the app service)